# Using JpaRepository difference between deleteBy and removeBy

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I have been testing out the delete feature for `JpaRepository` and have this (simplified) Interface:

```
@Repository
public interface BrowserInfoDao extends JpaRepository<BrowserInfo, String> {

    @Transactional
    public Integer deleteByClientGuidAndBrowserGuid(String clientGuid, String browserGuid);

    @Transactional
    public Integer removeByClientGuidAndBrowserGuid(String clientGuid, String browserGuid);

}
```

In my tests I can't find any behavioral difference between the removeBy and deleteBy method. So my question is what is the difference between these if any? Is there a best practice reason to use one over the other?

Note: I am using Hibernate as the implementation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are the same . Which one to choose depend on your personal preference.

For detail , please see [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-448). Code-wise, check out [PartTree](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/4be5aae181ad9930f409a93eb5a36697884c5c18/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/PartTree.java#L62) which defines the following regex pattern for matching these delete query:

```
private static final String DELETE_PATTERN = "delete|remove";
private static final Pattern PREFIX_TEMPLATE = Pattern.compile( //
        "^(" + QUERY_PATTERN + "|" + COUNT_PATTERN + "|" + DELETE_PATTERN + ")((\\p{Lu}.*?))??By");
```